# How to return information from the kth element of a linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Lets say I have a linked list that consists of {12,25,46,27,57} and I choose k to be 4. I'm hoping for a way to iterate through the list and only print 27 as my output.

I was also wondering how you would go about deleting a variable in the same fashion. So if I chose variable 3 from the list I would want the linked list to print as {12,25,27,57}.

Comment: Iterators. https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/iterator . You would want to meet the requirements of [*`LegacyRandomAccessIterator`*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) to have the easiest time of it.

Comment: Why haven't you posted any code that shows your linked-list implementation? This sounds like an undergrad homework question.

Comment: @Dai that's probably because it is.

Comment: If this is a school assignment, all of these basic operations should have been described in great detail in whatever data structures or algorithm book(s) you are using for your course.  Traversing and deleting from a linked list should have come with illustrations and pseudocode as to how to perform these operations.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, implement something like this:

```
Node * n=head;
for(int i=1; i<=k;i++){
    if(i==k){
        return n;
    }
    n=n->next;
}
```

For the second part, implement this:

```
Node * n=head;
Node * rightPatch=head;
Node * leftPatch =head;
for(int i=1; i<=k;i++){
    if(i->next=nullptr){
        rightPatch=nullptr;
        tail=leftPatch;
    }
    else{
        rightPatch=n->next;
    }
    if(i==k && i ==1){
        delete n;
        head=rightPatch;
        return;     
    }
    else if(i==k){
        delete n;
        leftPatch->next=rightPatch;
        return;
    }
    leftPatch=n;
    n=n->next;
}
```

The delete function is extremely common for students to mess up on and have segfaults, so make sure you understand it well. It's not too complicated, and it eventually becomes second nature. Also, make sure your functions handle outside cases like deleting on an empty list. Professors really want to see students take those into consideration when they code.

Comment: This isn't really C++ - what you've posted is more like "C with `new`/`delete`. When writing idiomatic C++ we should avoid `new`, `delete`, and raw-pointers as much as possible.

Comment: As a current undergrad myself, this is how an assignment is expected to look in C++. Lower division courses only use new and delete.

Comment: As a former professor who taught C++, your curriculum was out of date. Your experiences are not universal, the quicker you learn that, the easier life will be.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet implemented the list, then you could use [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), which provides a member erase() operation to erase an element. The link to std::list shows some examples and also shows how the std::list makes much use of the concept of an [iterator](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) to access elements in the list.
If you use std::list then then you can use the [std algorithm library](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/algorithm.htm) to work with the list. For example [std::find_if](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/cpp_algorithm_find_if.htm) will find the first element that satisfies the predicate you supply ( actually you can also use std::find for your example). To find the others matching in the list just keep on iterating...

If you need to implement your own list, then looking at std::list is a great place to start to see a possible way to do it.